# Particle system adds some pattern to a mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, particles, hair

Modelling a giraffe and adding hair particle system to it for making a fur, the result is absolutely trashy

[image]

As you may see particle system adds those triangles that as I know mean mistakes in polygon structure. When particles are turned off everything is ok. Here is wireframe:

[image]

Node structure for the material:

[image]

Particle system's settings:

[image]

Thank you in advance. You are always helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hair particles will reveal low-poly geometry like this in most cases. The best way to fix this is to use more geometry, making the model smoother. Try adding a subdivision surface modifier, or manually adding cuts and subdivisions to the model.
You could also try using some larger, longer particles, and maybe some more of them as well. This would help make the hair look more "full".